# c++ std::map::find to c# dictionary<key,val>

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, dictionary, stdmap

Once again with the language conversion.

I have a c++ std::map that I need to convert to C#.  I believe it is equivalent to a dictionary.

Where I really need to get an understanding is in the c++ code there is the map::find - I need to do a similar thing in C#, and haven't quite got it sussed yet.

C++ code block

```
map<int, CAG_StatementWriter*> m_Writer;
map<int, DWORD> m_Counter;

other program code ....

int nPhysicalPages = 1 + nTextPages / 2;  //Statement.m_nTotalPages
map<int, CAG_StatementWriter*>::iterator iter = m_Writer.find(nPhysicalPages);
if (iter == m_Writer.end() ||
(nPhysicalPages == 1 && m_Counter[1] % 2000 == 0) ||
(nPhysicalPages == 2 && m_Counter[2] % 1000 == 0)
)
{
// working code here
}
```

C# code block

```
public static Dictionary<int, Writer> sWriter = new Dictionary<int, Writer>();
public static Dictionary<int, int> Counter { get; set; }

other program code... 

int physicalPages = 1 + textPages / 2;
Dictionary<int, Writer>.ValueCollection iter = sWriter.<>(physicalPages);
if (iter == sWriter.<> ||
   (physicalPages == 1 && Counter[1] % 2000 == 0) ||
   (physicalPages == 2 && Counter[2] % 1000 == 0))
{
    // working code here
}
```

I am trying to figure out what would take the place of the c++  ::iterator.  I know ValueCollection is not correct; that is what I was trying when I decided to post the question.

Comment: Since you aren't actually using the iterator except to check whether or not the lookup was sucessful, I believe the equivalent would be [Dictionary.ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)  **EDIT:** Assuming `iter` isn't used inside the `// working code here` section.

Comment: Actually, std::map is sorted, so the .NET equivalent is SortedDictionary, not Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary's equivalent to find is TryGetValue. Unlike find which returns an iterator TryGetValue returns a boolean and takes an out parameter that receives the value if it is in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

C# has no iterators like c++

To find a value that may or may not be in the dictionary

```
Writer w = null;
if(sWriter.TryGetValue(physicalPage, out w))
{
   // found and w has the found Writer object
}
```

if you know its there (or dont mind throwing if its not)

```
Writer w = sWriter[physicalPage];
```